# How do I apply CSS to a Submit button

Tags: php, css, forms, button, submit

So I have these CSS attributes currently being applied to the word login

```
 <div class="login_btn">Login</div><!-- The login button-->
```

And here is the CSS

```
            .login_btn, .submit_btn{
            clear: both;
            width: 80px;
            text-align:center;
            background: #4C7FEB;
            color: #fff;
            text-transform: uppercase;
            border: 1px solid #4C7FEB;
            padding: 16px 40px;
            margin: 0 auto;
            -webkit-transition: color 0.2s,background-color 0.2s,box-shadow 0.2s,border 0.2s;
            -moz-transition: color 0.2s,background-color 0.2s,box-shadow 0.2s,border 0.2s;
            -o-transition: color 0.2s,background-color 0.2s,box-shadow 0.2s,border 0.2s;
            transition: color 0.2s,background-color 0.2s,box-shadow 0.2s,border 0.2s;
            -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
            -moz-border-radius: 3px;
            border-radius: 3px;
            -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
            -moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
            box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
        }
        .login_btn:hover{
            background: #285AC5;
            box-shadow: none;
        }
```

I am really struggling to take this code and apply it to a submit button.

```
<input  id="login_btn" name="" value="" type="submit" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to put the class in the input element like this:

```
<input class="login_btn" id="login_btn" name="" value="" type="submit" />
```

Comment: Oh I see, I was trying to use the div tag but that didn't work and then I thought id might work! Ty very much :) However now the button for some reason is stuck on the side instead of centred with the word Login in it like the previous one?

Answer (score 1):

Add the same css, here:
    #login_btn {
        // Css code here
    }

Answer (score 0):

you can use this

```
input[type=submit]{
    clear: both;
    width: 80px;
    text-align:center;
    background: #4C7FEB;
    color: #fff;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    border: 1px solid #4C7FEB;
    padding: 16px 40px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    -webkit-transition: color 0.2s,background-color 0.2s,box-shadow 0.2s,border 0.2s;
    -moz-transition: color 0.2s,background-color 0.2s,box-shadow 0.2s,border 0.2s;
    -o-transition: color 0.2s,background-color 0.2s,box-shadow 0.2s,border 0.2s;
    transition: color 0.2s,background-color 0.2s,box-shadow 0.2s,border 0.2s;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}
input[type=submit]:hover{
    background: #285AC5;
    box-shadow: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access the button by its ID, like this:

```
#login_btn {
    background: #285AC5;
}
```

You are now trying to access it by the class name (the "." operator).

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
input[type="submit"]
{
    //Your styles here
}
```

**Warning: This will apply the define style to all submit buttons. So make sure that this is what you want.**

If you just want to apply this style to only one submit button use its id or css class as shown below.

```
#login_btn, .login_btn {
    //Your style here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add class to your button

to

```
<input  class="login_btn" id="login_btn" name="" value="" type="submit" />
```

or add this to your css

```
#login_btn, .login_btn, .submit_btn{ ... }
```

Answer (score -2):

this is two buttons one with div and one with input button. sample at below link and code is below

check this sample which is working..   jsfiddle.net/WG2jX/

```
 <div class="login_btn">Login</div><!-- The login button-->
 <input  class="login_btns" name="" value="Login" type="submit" />
```

and css will be

```
.login_btn {
        clear: both;
        width: 80px;
        text-align:center;
        background: #4C7FEB;
        color: #fff;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        border: 1px solid #4C7FEB;
        padding: 16px 40px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        -webkit-transition: color 0.2s,background-color 0.2s,box-shadow 0.2s,border 0.2s;
        -moz-transition: color 0.2s,background-color 0.2s,box-shadow 0.2s,border 0.2s;
        -o-transition: color 0.2s,background-color 0.2s,box-shadow 0.2s,border 0.2s;
        transition: color 0.2s,background-color 0.2s,box-shadow 0.2s,border 0.2s;
        -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
        -moz-border-radius: 3px;
        border-radius: 3px;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
        -moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
        box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    }
    .login_btn:hover{
        background: #285AC5;
        box-shadow: none;
    }
.login_btns {
        clear: both;
        width: 160px;
        text-align:center;
        background: #4C7FEB;
        color: #fff;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        border: 1px solid #4C7FEB;
        padding: 16px 40px;
        margin: 0 auto;
font-size:22px;
        -webkit-transition: color 0.2s,background-color 0.2s,box-shadow 0.2s,border 0.2s;
        -moz-transition: color 0.2s,background-color 0.2s,box-shadow 0.2s,border 0.2s;
        -o-transition: color 0.2s,background-color 0.2s,box-shadow 0.2s,border 0.2s;
        transition: color 0.2s,background-color 0.2s,box-shadow 0.2s,border 0.2s;
        -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
        -moz-border-radius: 3px;
        border-radius: 3px;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
        -moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
        box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    }
    .login_btns:hover{
        background: #285AC5;
        box-shadow: none;
    }
```

Comment: answers to questions must contain some of the code (if code is relevant). It's not acceptable to simply post a link to fiddle. Please edit your question to include a full answer.